# Is Micronaut a right choice for micro-services which call other HTTP microservices?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

Hi Micronaut Development Community

We are trying to create Micronaut based microservices(in Java) which make calls to other HTTP services and Database(both Dynamo DB and RDS on AWS). What are the recommended Micronaut libraries/http client, to ensure the end to end flow remains reactive?

We have implemented the microservices using micronaut, but there are Read Timeout issues appearing for higher loads - is that expected?

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: You are asking too many questions and I recommend to separate these into individual questions

Comment: Thanks @saw303 - updated the question to one point only.

Answer (score 1):

Resources:

[Micronaut Documentation:](https://docs.micronaut.io/index.html)

See [Micronaut User Guide](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/), it has sections on [6.13 Reactive HTTP Request Processing](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#reactiveServer) (Reactor/RxJava)

> 6.13 Reactive HTTP Request Processing
>
> As mentioned previously, Micronaut is built on Netty which is designed around an Event loop model and non-blocking I/O. Micronaut executes code defined in @Controller beans in the same thread as the request thread (an Event Loop thread).
>
> This makes it critical that if you do any blocking I/O operations (for example interactions with Hibernate/JPA or JDBC) that you offload those tasks to a separate thread pool that does not block the Event loop.

^ Might be the cause of your read timeouts ^

[Micronaut Guides:](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/index.html)

- [Micronaut Data with R2BC](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-r2dbc-repository.html)
- [Hibernate Reactive Guides](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/tag-reactive.html)

Support:

- [Community Support](https://micronaut.io/resources/community-support/)
- [Commercial Support](https://micronaut.io/support/)
- [Professional Training](https://micronaut.io/professional-training/https://micronaut.io/professional-training/)